# Mysql database запрос select

Tags: mysql, база-данных

есть таблица
[image: таблица]

нужно с помощью запроса select

1. вывести все картонные упаковки с 3 литрами
2. вывести все пластмассовые упаковки с 3 литрами кроме вишнёвого сока

а также как добавить столбец и вставить туда данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `SELECT *FROM (впиши название таблицы без скобок)  where упаковка="картонная" and литры=3;`

2) `SELECT *FROM (название) where упаковка="пластмассовая" and литры=3 and сок!="вишневый";`

3) `ALTER TABLE  (название таблицы) ADD (название столбца);`

тут вроде и тип нужен, но сам разберешься

```
INSERT INTO (название таблицы) (название нового столбца в скобках) 
       VALUES (нужное значение в скобках).
```

Вроде все, с синтаксисом может быть ошибка, раз ты щас это решаешь, должен суметь исправить

Answer (score 0):

1. `select 'поле сок', 'поле упаковка', 'поле литры'  from 'имя таблицы' where  'поле упаковка' = 'картонная' and 'поле литры' = 3`

А остальные попробуйте сделать сами на основе этой конструкции. Если уже что-то не получится, спрашивайте с примером своего кода. Тут не любят вопросы без собственных попыток.

Последний вопрос решается через `ALTER TABLE`